# Customer Attrition Modeling

Tags: logistic, survival

I am building a customer attrition model for a commercial banking client. I am having difficulty defining target variable - customer attrition. In the data set, i can have multiple records for a single customer. Suppose a customer holds multiple accounts (or products) so there would be multiple records for a customer. The question arises - Should i calculate attrition at customer level or multiple models for each products? I know it all depends on the objective of the study. Is it possible to calculate customer attrition at customer level (aggregating information of multiple products)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. If your end objective is if a customer has attrited or not, then you have to see if he has stopped using all the products and (if you have the information), will not be using the products anymore.

So, the type of product becomes irrelevant in such a case. However, if you want to map attrition on a product level basis, you have to check whether he has stopped using that specific product.